# Trigger code after passing all checks in MM01 but before DB commit?

Tags: sap-erp

I have checked some of the MM01 userexits but does not suffice what I need to happen.

My enhancement should only be triggered once material is already extended, preferably after save to DB. I used this `EXIT_SAPLMGMU_001` but it is triggering my enhancement upon saving not after save.

Comment: What means *"upon saving not after save"* ? You wanna validate material before save?

Comment: @Suncatcher , yes, the exit above is always triggered upon saving. For sample, I did not enter value for old material number which is a required field.. Since the exit is triggered already, the material is not yet extended, therefore not yet in MARC table but then, my enhancement already worked. What I need is to trigger enhancement when material is already extended.. So should be triggered After Save.

Comment: @Suncatcher desired is to trigger enhancement once all data are validated. So should be after save. The exit i mentioned above triggers even if other required fields are not populated yet and that should be not.

Comment: how did you solved this problem finally? and did you?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try a different approach and use the Workflow eventing system (SWETYPV) to either start an entire Workflow or simply register a custom event handler once the material has been created.

Comment: I would consider that, but I think there is an exit/badi, Just have to explore it more first. Thanks anyway.